# About type parameter of generic in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm studying kotlin language and I can't distinguish these examples, especially nullable types in a 'where' clause of generic.
Would you tell me the difference?

case 1

```
class Foo<T> where T: Comparable<T>
class Foo<T> where T: Comparable<T?>
class Foo<T> where T: Comparable<T>?
class Foo<T> where T: Comparable<T?>?
```

case 2

```
class Foo<T> where T: Comparable<T>? {
// If a class is declared like above, is a type 'T' already nullable?

// Then, 
fun bar(value: T?) { // Should I declare a member function like this to accept null or
// do something
}

fun bar(value: T) { // Should I declare like this instead?
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to distinguish `T : Comparable<T>` and `T : Comparable<T?>`, take a look at the following example. The difference is whether you can compare `T` with `T?`.

```
class Bar1(var bar : Int) : Comparable<Bar1>{

    override fun compareTo(other : Bar1) : Int {
        return bar - other.bar
    }
}

class Bar2(var bar : Int) : Comparable<Bar2?>{

    override fun compareTo(other : Bar2?) : Int {
        return bar - ( other?.bar ?: 0 )
    }
}

fun main(){
    println(Bar1(1) > Bar1(2))
    val bar2 : Bar2? = Bar2(2)
    println(Bar2(1) > bar2)
}
```

Output:

> false
>
> false

The difference is that

```
val bar1 : Bar1? = Bar1(2)
println(Bar1(1) > bar1)
```

will not compile. `bar1` must be unwrapped

Second, to distinguish `class Foo<T> where T: Comparable<T>?` and `class Foo<T> where T: Comparable<T>?`, it has nothing to do with comparable. Take a look at the following simplified example.

```
class Foo1<T>(val t : T) where T : Int{
    override fun toString() : String{
        return "$t"
    }
}

class Foo2<T>(val t : T) where T : Int?{
    override fun toString() : String{
        return "$t"
    }
}


fun main(){
    println(Foo1(5))
    val i : Int? = 5
    println(Foo2(i))
}
```

Output:

> 5
>
> 5

The difference is that `println(Foo1(i))` will not compile. `i` must be unwrapped.